# what is best way to storage big number with ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, blockchain, biginteger, bigdecimal

I want to use ElasticSearch to storage blockchain wei value. But I have problem with big integer (example: '30000000000000000000') "reason"=>"[1:230] Numeric value (30000000000000000000) out of range of long (-9223372036854775808 - 9223372036854775807)

Does ElasticSearch support Big Number or Decimal type?

If no, is there any efficient way to work with Big Number without loss precision ?